# child module not found in maven multi project execution

Tags: maven

I created two projects(PROJECT-1,PROJECT-2) in the directory and i would like to execute both the projects in one click for that i create another project(PROJECT-3) in the directory and present these two projects((PROJECT-1,PROJECT-2) as **modules** and define packaging as `pom` Here i am using modules concept.

```
<modules>
  <module>D:/20-6-2014/PROJECT-1</module>
  <module>D:/20-6-2014/PROJECT-2</module>
</module>
```

I define the PROJECT-3 as parent for both the projects,while i run the PROJECT-3 it gives an error.

> Error is: Child module D:\20-6-2014\PROJECT-3\PROJECT-1 of
>   D:\20-6-2014\PROJECT-3\POM.XML does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

your directory structure should be like as follows PROJECT-3 is your parent project for PROJECT-1 and PROJECT-2

```
|
|
----PROJECT-3
    |
    |
    ----pom.xml
    |
    |
    ----PROJECT-1
    |        |
    |        |
    |        ------pom.xml
    ----PROJECT-2
            |
            |
            -------pom.xml
```

and PROJECT-3's `pom.xml` should have

```
<modules>
  <module>PROJECT-1</module>
  <module>PROJECT-2</module>
</module>
```

Comment: I did the same but the error comes again can you observe the above specified error.

Comment: can you add your directory structure and pom.xmls for all 3 project in question

Comment: be aware that modules should contain relative paths (to make it portable)